GLM with clustered SE or GLMER
I'm doing an experiment of behavioral economics with 113 subjects that each answered to 6 questions randomly picked out of 10. My dependent variable is binary (Error=0 or Error=1) and I'm using a logistic regression.  I don't know what to chose between GMLER with individuals random effects or GLM and then clustering SE at the individual level. I thought both would control for intra-individual correlation + GMLER adds also inter-individual variability. I tried both models but I get very different results and I'm unsure on how to interpret it and which model to chose ... Especially I don't really understand why all my coefficient are significant in GMLER but not in GLM. Does it mean that the random effects captured part of the unexplained variance? And hence that GMLER is a better model? It feels like my p-values are "too-good to be true" ...
I did two logistic regressions using GLM (up) and GLMER (down) and compared the results. I get very different standards errors and p-values ... Which one should I trust?

# glm
model2 <- glm(Error ~ Complexity + Response_time + 
              Response_time:Complexity, family = binomial("logit"), 
              data = B)
clustered_se2 <- coeftest(model2, 
       vcov. = vcovCR(model2, cluster = B$Individual, type = "CR2"))
p_values2 <- clustered_se2[, 4]

# glmer
model <- glmer(Error ~ Complexity + Response_time + 
    Response_time:Complexity + (1 | Individual), 
    family = binomial("logit"), data = B)


